# Does a non-EU citizen with Schengen visa have to provide proof of assets when crossing from the EU to Bulgaria, Cyprus or Romania?

Tags: proof-of-funds, land-borders, schengen-visas, albanian-citizens

I am an Albanian citizen and I have a multiple entry visa from Germany (I currently work there). If I have to cross over to Bulgaria, Cyprus or Romania do I have to provide proof of financial assets? Once I was in Bulgaria I didn't need to. Now I am a bit skeptical.

Comment: According to Romanian OUG 194/2002 the short-term visitors [might] need to provide proof of sufficient funds 50EUR/day but not less than 500E. Accepted are any forms of cash, traveler's checks, checking accounts, credit cards (with up-to-date statements) or any other means of proof. However this is rarely checked unless there are strong suspicions that the person cannot sustain him-/herself. I suspect the same for all the other countries. A printout of the bank account balance would probably suffice in case you get asked.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I dont understand less than 500 euros? If u stay 2 days u still need to show 500? I still find it that the person there wanted to play with the people rather then obeing the rules which is not fair.

Comment: It's minimum 500E for 2 days. However I wouldn't worry about that too much, it's better perhaps to show some proof of stay in Germany (Anmeldung, rent contract copy, ...). An EU credit/debit card should also be enough since they cannot check it. The [lately] enhanced border checks are mostly a measure to curb illegal immigration into Germany. Since you already are located in DE I doubt they will ask any questions. However they might do that on your way back.

Answer (score 1):

Because you would be entering under short-stay rules, you must, among other things, **have sufficient financial means** to cover expenses during your trip and the return to your country of residence. Border guards can ask about if and if you fail to demonstrate that you fulfil the requirement, they can deny entry on that basis alone. It is a legal requirement and one of the standard reasons on the refusal of entry form.

But it does not mean that border guards ask each and every traveller crossing the border to produce bank statements or the like and it's certainly not required to have cold hard cash on your person. **In most cases, you won't actually need to show anything** and if they do ask, a credit card should be enough.

How thorough the border check is varies a bit but statistics show that in some countries it lasts something like 30 s on average. That's not a lot of time. So you can expect a couple of questions about the purpose of stay while the guard is looking up your name, visa and passport number in the relevant databases (to check whether you have been banned or flagged as dangerous, whether your passport has been reported as stolen or your visa cancelled). They would only move on to a more thorough evaluation (which might include questions about financial means) for a limited number of people.

Comment: But this is not written anywhere because I had to read a lot of portals. They can have the right to ask only if I go purely with my albanian passport (not any schengen visa to cover) and this change has been made from 2014, febbruary. Where is written this extra thing because I dont find it written anywhere.

Comment: @ElonaGusho Yes the rules are quite hard to track down. My answer is based on the fact that those countries have to apply Schengen rules (even though they are not part of the Schengen area at the moment) as described in the Schengen Borders code. Also, these rules fully apply to Schengen visa holders. Since you work there, I assume that you have a German long-stay visa or residence permit and the rules also apply in this case but Schengen countries are supposed to allow you to transit on your way to Germany even if you don't fulfil all the requirements.

Comment: These rules haven't changed much over the years, what happens is that countries are moved from one category (visa required) to another. But that doesn't matter, the financial means requirement applies to all third-country nationals, visa or no-visa.